# Does bouncyCastle provide TLS capability?

Tags: java, ssl, bouncycastle

I feel I should offer some explanation of why I want to implement what seems like a bad solution....

I'm a systems admin, not a java programmer, and have inherited a large and diverse estate of applications running Java 1.7 in Tomcat.

While I am keen to get these all upgraded, this requires the time and cooperation of the development team. My biggest concern (rather topically) is removal of SSLv3, TLS/1.0 and TLS/1.1 from the network. SSL termination for incoming connections is handled by proxy so I can (in principle) stop exposing the vulnerabilities in the services there, however that will break the integration between components running in seperate JVMs and communicating via HTTPS (e.g. CAS authentication).

(yes I could run separate internal/external proxies or use direct addressing bypassing the proxy....but this seems even more of a hack)

Which brings me to my question....

Does BouncyCastle only provide ciphersuites or does it provide TLS?

If I install [bouncycastle as a provider](https://bouncycastle.org/wiki/display/JA1/Provider+Installation) will these older java applications be able to make HTTPS client requests using TLS/1.2 or are further code changes required?

Comment: Are you sure that you need external library? From quick googling it seems like Java 7 supports TLS 1.2.

Comment: As is hopefully clear from their website, bouncycastle has a separate library (bctls) to implement TLS.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

BouncyCastle provider will allow you to use ciphers not supported by the jvm. However, depending on your jvm version, the tls 1.2 protocol might not be supported. It appears java 7 should be able to support it.

Either way, to enforce the use of tls1.2, you need further configuration, but not necesserally code changes. You servers must be configured to use it exclusively (configuration may be vendor-specific). Your clients may be configured to use tls1.2 only as well (using -Dhttps.protocols for instance).

See https://blogs.oracle.com/java-platform-group/diagnosing-tls,-ssl,-and-https for more information.

Comment: Indirectly that seems to answer my question: no, bouncycastle does not provide TLS, only ciphersuites. Unfortunately as I am on an older version of Java than 1.7.0.95, I am looking at an upgrade. And that would be just as disruptive as going to 1.8.x :(